# Google Maps Javascript API Retina Polylines?

Tags: google-maps

For the life of me I can't find anything on Google regarding this. Google Maps Javascript API 3.0 has beautiful Retina tiles but any Polyline rendered on it looks terrible. It's to wonder if there's anyone within Google that has a Retina screen. Any known workaround on making Polylines look good on Retina?

Comment: retina.js from imulus?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Google recently made some changes (perhaps with API v3.20) because I see retina polygons/polylines now, which is awesome.